# java toString representation

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to see if the method `public String toString()` is representing correctly the polynomial function. I don't know how to give the coefficients from main so that the class `Func` receives them.

```
package ro.utcluj.poo.lab04;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Func {

    public double[] coef; //the coefficients
    public int nrCoef;  //coefficients number


    public Func(double[] input)
    {
        nrCoef = input.length;
        this.coef = new double[nrCoef];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < input.length; counter++)
            coef[counter] = input[counter];

    }
    public double getFuncValue(double x)
    {           
        double exponent = nrCoef;
        double y = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        for(int i = nrCoef; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            y = coef[i]*Math.pow(x, exponent-1); //n grade polynomial function

            exponent--;
            sum += y; //the sume for each member
        }
        return sum;
    }



    public double getDerivValue(double x)
    {
        double deriv = 0;
        double rezDeriv = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < nrCoef - 1; i++)
        {
            deriv = coef[i]*(nrCoef - i)*Math.pow(x, nrCoef - i -1);
            rezDeriv += deriv;
        }

        return rezDeriv;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = new String(" ");
        int exp = nrCoef-1;

        for(int i = 0; i < nrCoef; i++)
        {
            if(exp == 0 && coef[i] > 0)
                s +="+" + coef[i];
            else if(exp == 0 && coef[i] < 0)
                s +=coef[i];
            else if(exp == 1 && coef[i] > 0 && i == 0)
                s +="+" + coef[i] + "x";
            else if(exp == 1 && coef[i] >0)
                s +="+" + coef[i];
            else if(exp == 1 && coef[i] < 0)
                s+=coef[i];
            else if(coef[i] == 0)
                s += "";
            else if(coef[i] > 0 && i!=0)
                s +="+" + coef[i]+"x^" + exp;
            else
                s +=coef[i] + "x^" + exp;
            exp--;  
            System.out.println(s);
        }   

        return s;
    }   
}
```

.

```
public class Main04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] v = new double[]{3,5,4};
        Func f = new Func(v);

    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(f)` (this will call `toString()` on `f`)?

Comment: It looks like you already *have* passed the co-efficients through to your `Func` instance; that's what the `v` parameter in `new Func(v);` is doing!

Comment: You should also avoid string concatenation (use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for that)

Comment: You don't need to call the `System.out.println(s);` in the `toString()` method, you just need to call `System.out.println(f);` in your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see what `toString()` does on your object `f` in `main`, all you need to do is

```
System.out.println(f);
```

`f` already has the coefficients that you passed into its constructor. `println` will call the object's `toString()` method and output the resulting string for you to see.

Also, as Steven pointed out in the comments, you don't need to put:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

in your `toString()` method itself. `toString` is supposed to produce and return the string. Your `main` method can deal with printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

That worked but if I give the values {-3, -5, -4} I receive this:

```
-3.0x^2-5.0-4.0
```

It's missing the **x** from the second term(-5.0x). That is happining only if the second value is a negative one. For positive values it's working fine.

Comment: I found the problem. There was missing an **x** at: else if(exp == 1 && coef[i] < 0) s+=coef[i] + **"x"**;

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to see what toString() does on object `f` in `main`...
You only have to yo use :
`System.out.println(f);`
This method will print the result of toString() to the command line. 
That's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

class Func {

```
public double[] coef; // the coefficients
public int nrCoef; // coefficients number
private StringBuilder sbl = new StringBuilder();
private StringBuilder tsbl = new StringBuilder();

public Func(double[] input) {
    nrCoef = input.length;
    this.coef = new double[nrCoef];

    sbl.append("\nF(x) = ");
    int exp = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < nrCoef; counter++) {
        coef[counter] = input[counter];
        if (coef[counter] != 0) {
            if (counter != 0) {
                sbl.append(coef[counter] < 0 ? " - " : " + ");
            } else if (coef[counter] < 0) {
                sbl.append(" - ");
            }
            exp = nrCoef - counter - 1;
            sbl.append(Math.abs(coef[counter])+(exp == 0 ? "" : exp == 1 ?  "*x" : "*x^"+exp));
        }
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return tsbl.toString().isEmpty() ? sbl.toString() : tsbl.toString();
}

public double getFuncValue(double x) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < nrCoef; index++) {
        sum += coef[index] * Math.pow(x, nrCoef - index - 1); // n grade polynomial
    }
    tsbl = new StringBuilder();
    tsbl.append(sbl.toString());
    tsbl.append("\nF(");
    tsbl.append(x);
    tsbl.append(") = "+sum);
    return sum;
}
```

...